# Getting HTML element value from a specific id via Python

Tags: python, html, bottle

So, I have a Bottle page within PythonAnywhere that is displaying a list of items in my SQLite database. In each of those tappable items, I want to give the other page relevant information from the database based on the name of the list item that was clicked.

So in this case, I want to grab the value of this element and use the variable in my SQLite query via Python.

```
<ons-list-item id="itembtn" name="itembtn" value="{{ record [0] }}" tappable>
```

However, it is to my knowledge that the value of an HTML element isn't possible to retrieve. I am wondering if anyone knows of a way to grab this dynamic value with Python.

```
<!-- Parts showing from database -->
        <template id="caseFanResult.html">
            <% result = c.execute("SELECT * FROM caseFanPart")%>
                <ons-page id="caseFanResult">
                    <ons-toolbar>
                        <div class="left">
                            <ons-back-button>Back</ons-back-button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="center">Case Fan Parts</div>
                    </ons-toolbar>
                    <ons-list modifier="material">
                        %for record in result:
                        <ons-list-item id="itembtn" name="itembtn" value="{{ record [0] }}" tappable>
                            <div class="center">
                                <span class="list-item__title">{{ record[1] }}</span>
                                <span class="list-item__subtitle">{{ record[2] }}</span>
                            </div>
                        </ons-list-item>
                        %end
                    </ons-list>
                </ons-page>
        </template>

        <!-- Parts detailed spec sheet -->
        <template id="itemResult.html">
            <% 
            id = request.form.get("itembtn","")
            itemResult = c.execute("SELECT * FROM caseFanPart WHERE caseFanID = ?", (id,))
            %>

                <ons-page id="itemResult">
                    <ons-toolbar>
                        <div class="left">
                            <ons-back-button>Back</ons-back-button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="center">Spec Sheet</div>
                    </ons-toolbar>
                    <ons-list modifier="material">
                        %for item in itemResult:
                        <ons-list-header>{{ item[1] }}</ons-list-header>
                        <ons-list-item>Price: {{ item[2] }}</ons-list-item>
                        <ons-list-item>Rating: {{ item[3] }}</ons-list-item>
                        <ons-list-item>Color: {{ item[4] }}</ons-list-item>
                        <ons-list-item>Size: {{ item[5] }}</ons-list-item>
                        <ons-list-item>RPM: {{ item[6] }}</ons-list-item>
                        <ons-list-item>Airflow: {{ item[7] }}</ons-list-item>
                        <ons-list-item>Noise Level:{{ item[8] }}</ons-list-item>
                        %end
                    </ons-list>
                </ons-page>
        </template>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what you have to do to extract a value from an HTML element

```
import bs4 as bs

word = '<ons-list-item id="itembtn" name="itembtn" value="{{ record [0] }}" tappable>'

soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(word,'lxml')

supa = soup.find('ons-list-item',attrs={'id' : 'itembtn'})

value = supa.get('value')
#print(value)

#to find all values 
valuelist = []
supa = soup.find_all('ons-list-item',attrs={'id' : 'itembtn'})
for val in supa: 
    value = val.get('value')
    valuelist.append(value)
print(valuelist)
```

Comment: this seems like an amazing idea, but looping through all of the values doesn't seem to work. The goal is to grab the values of each record and use that as the value for the sqlite query. So when you click one list item, it will transfer it's corresponding value number to the next page to display relevant information. Any ideas on this?